# Radon test results came back at 26 pCi/L, is it safe to use my basement?

Tags: radon

My Radon Test Report just came back and it says that my basement has 26.2 pCi/L. The basement is where we exercise, so I'm wondering if it's safe to do so. I know the acceptable levels is dramatically lower 2 - 4 pCi/L, so I am a bit concerned as we wait for our radon remediation system to be installed.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a "safety" question, not a home improvement question since you've already decided to get a radon remediation system installed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement.

Comment: You might be able to get an answer on [biology.se] or [medicalsciences.se] but read the help there to make sure that the question is on-topic. My gut says that if the reading is 10x the safe level, you should probably avoid _strenuous exercise_ there until the system is installed and has cleared the air, but that's just a hunch and nothing scientific.

Comment: That's like a chest xray for every 8 hours spent down there. You don't have to hold your breath to flip the laundry, but i would exercise somewhere else until it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no safe level of radiation/radon exposure. It's recommended to have the lowest levels possible to reduce the risks of lung cancer.

EPA recommends homes be fixed if the radon level is 4 pCi/L (picocurries per liter) or more. Because there is no known safe level of exposure to radon, EPA also recommends that Americans consider fixing their home for radon levels between 2 pCi/L and 4 pCi/L.

https://www.epa.gov/radon/what-epas-action-level-radon-and-what-does-it-mean